# Granger causality does not imply a pair of integrated time series are cointegrated: an example

Tags: time-series, cointegration, granger-causality

If a pair of integrated time series $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ are cointegrated, at least one of them must Granger-cause the other. Is the converse also true? I guess not, but I am struggling to come up with a counterexample. Could you help me?

Comment: Granger's representation theorem might be a useful avenue for further analysis.

Comment: @ChristophHanck, OK, but do you know the answer? I would be curious to learn it first before trying to figure out the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Z_t\}$ be independent random walks. Let
$$
Y_t:=X_{t-1}+Z_t.
$$
Both $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ are integrated processes that are not cointegrated. However, I will show that $\{X_t\} \xrightarrow{\text{Granger}} \{Y_t\}$.

Under square loss, what is the best forecast $\hat Y_{t|t-1}$ of $Y_t$ that we may obtain using only the past values of $\{Y_t\}$? In other words, what is $\mathbb{E}(Y_t\mid Y_{t-1},Y_{t-2},\dots)?$ Since $\{Y_t\}$ is a random walk, it is $\hat Y_{t|t-1} = Y_{t-1}$. The forecast error is $Y_t - \hat Y_{t|t-1} = Y_t - Y_{t-1} = \Delta Y_t = \Delta X_{t-1} + \Delta Z_{t-1}$.

Can we improve upon this forecast by using the past values of $\{X_t\}$ in addition to the past values of $\{Y_t\}$? Yes, we can, because $\Delta X_{t-1} = X_{t-1} - X_{t-2}$ is determined by the past values of $\{X_t\}$. Thus the improved forecast is $\tilde Y_{t|t-1} = Y_{t-1} + \Delta X_{t-1}$ with a forecast error of $\Delta Z_{t-1}$.

Since we can predict $Y_t$ more accurately using the history of $X_t$ in addition to the history of $Y_t$, $\{X_t\} \xrightarrow{\text{Granger}} \{Y_t\}$.

Comment: that looks good to me, +1!

Comment: @ChristophHanck, thank you!